# If knives and fists are all considered light weapons, what's the benefit of picking up such weapons?

Tags: weapons, unarmed-combat, cypher-system

If weapons like knives, small guns, and a fist punch are all considered light weapons, why would a player ever pick up a knife if they drop it in a fight (from a bad roll, for instance)?

Sure, they can "do" different things (e.g. a knife cuts; fists don't). But if you spend a round picking it up or just punching with your fist, players start wondering if they really need to care to much about light weapons when they always have a fist.

Comment: Can't tell for the cypher system, but in real life picking up the knife you dropped actually is often, I dare say usually, a bad idea during a fight. So cool for the Cypher System for reflecting that.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming that your character is not specifically built for it to matter, it does not matter whether you use the knife or your fists.**

In Cypher System, weapons generally only exist as light/medium/heavy and melee/ranged, and within those categories all have the same properties. That means any one light melee weapon is the same 2 damage with an asset on attacks as any other.

There are a handful of situations where the type of weapon *does* matter, though I'm not going to comb through all of the Cypher System... systems looking for them. I can, however, give the example of *Numenera*'s Glaive Type.

Glaives in *Numenera* choose a particular type of weapon to gain certain bonuses with as they tier up, beginning with a bonus to damage. In this case, the game gets a little more granular with what that type is, dividing weapons up into light/medium/heavy and **bladed/bashing**/ranged. So a Glaive could choose to specialize in "light bladed" weapons, getting a +1 to damage with them. In this case, there is an incentive to pick the dagger back up.

Comment: +1.  Is there any reason to specialize in "light bladed" weapons, then, when a character could instead specialize in "light bashing" weapons and do fistfighting?

Comment: @DanB Not off the top of my head, but I can't rule it out as, given how Cypher System character creation works, that would require knowing all the possible abilities for every type/focus. I can say that I don't know of any situation off the top of my head (knowing mostly Numenera) where specifically "light bladed" weapons would be worth specializing in. Cypher is not really interested in being a combat simulator anyways, and so the honest answer would likely just be "character flavor".